# How to fix : unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace?

Tags: oracle, create-table, tablespace

I'm trying to add 10m data to my database table and at about 3,5m it stopped and I got the error

> unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace.

I've never encountered that before and I have no idea how to fix it.

I'm running my scripts through sqlplus.

**My code**

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS (
ID_ADDRESS INTEGER NOT NULL,
STREET VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
HOUSE_NUMBER NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
FK_ID_CITY NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
);
```

**filling code**

```
EXEC ui.fillAddress(10000000);
```

[image]

**the solution i tried but didn't work**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oracle uses his own disk space allocation system, which lies on top of (or, under, depending how you view it) the OS filesystem. So, your disk may have lots of space, but your database is not configured to be allowed to use that disk space.

Comment: this really isn't helping in any way.

Comment: Maybe Google can help you ?

Comment: i tried what google offered but cmd said i had no rights to trigger the sql statement

Comment: If you continue to not display any command, error message, etc, you're bound to get vague replies. -- CMD, as in the Windows Command Interpreter ?

Comment: here you go i updated my post. any solutions now :( ?